# Model Properties are dynamic

Tags: php, lithium

I come from a .net background so the empty classes (models) that I'm seeing in Lithium is unsettling.
In .net, I don't have a property unless I do something like:

```
public class MyClass()
   public property myProp as string
end class
```

and then I set or get the property like so:

```
dim aClass as myClass
aClass.myProp = "some string"
dim myString as String = aClass.myProp
```

What I'm seeing in Lithium are dynamic objects a la javascript.
I can declare an arbitrary object and add properties as I go. 
Now, I'm not saying this is a bad thing, I just want to know:

1. If this is normal for PHP or normal for Lithium, and
2. If I add properties (so I can get code completion in eclipse), will it hurt the ORM features of Lithium?

Comment: Enjoy not having to modify your code whenever you add a field to the database!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lithium is fairly advanced and takes advantage of some PHP features that many frameworks do not.  You can add properties directly to objects in PHP, but, when using a framework, you want to look at what the best practices are and how it will impact your application.

In Lithium, `MyModel::create()` or `MyModel::find()` return entity objects or collections of entity objects that represent database records or documents.

Entity properties are stored in the protected `$_updated` and `$_data` arrays and accessed via `__get` and `__set` methods.

So, when you reference `$myModel->title`, you're getting/setting `$myModel->_updated['title']`.

Then, when you call `$myModel->save()`, the data in `$_updated` is saved to the database record or document.

See https://github.com/UnionOfRAD/lithium/blob/master/data/Entity.php for more details.

Comment: so that means its a lithium thing, and coding in actual properties is a bad thing?  (again, only harping on it for code completion. If its a not a good idea to code in properties, I'm good with not doing it)

Comment: Right.  You'll want to stay away from it when working with entity data.  Enjoy working with Lithium!

Comment: You don't say this explicitly, but I *think* adding properties will short-circuit the mapping that Lithium does; your changes will not go into the `$_updated` array and won't get saved to the database. So adding the properties manually will actually cause problems.

Comment: If you're obtaining the entity through Model::create() or Model::find(), you're not actually extending the Entity object.  Simply setting $myModel->customField = 1 will set that value in the $_updated array.  I haven't found a need to extend the Entity object yet as the entity returned by the model handles the field mapping perfectly.